# Why am I unable to push large files to GitHub despite tracking with Git LFS?

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I'm facing an issue while trying to push a large file (src/data/indonesia-cities.json, size: 139.64 MB) to GitHub. I understand that GitHub has a 100 MB file size limit, so I tried using Git Large File Storage (Git LFS) to handle it.

Steps Taken:

1. Installed Git LFS.
2. Tracked the large file with `git lfs track "src/data/indonesia-cities.json"`
3. Added `.gitattributes` and committed the changes.
   Here's the sequence of commands I used:

```bash
git lfs install
git lfs track "src/data/indonesia-cities.json"
git add .gitattributes
git commit -m "Track large files with Git LFS"
git push
```

Despite following these steps, I'm still getting an error message when trying to push to GitHub:

```bash
remote: error: File src/data/indonesia-cities.json is 139.64 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

[image]

What I've Tried:

1. Untracked the file and committed that change.
2. Re-tracked the file with Git LFS and committed the change.
3. Forced a push to update the remote branch.
   None of these steps have resolved the issue. I'm still unable to push the large file.

How can I resolve this issue and successfully push the large file to GitHub using Git LFS?

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by using Git LFS's migrate command. Here are the steps to resolve the problem:

Step 1: Install Git LFS
First, if you haven't already installed Git LFS, you can do so with the following command:

```bash
git lfs install
```

Step 2: Use git lfs migrate
To move the large file into Git LFS, use the migrate command as follows:

```bash
git lfs migrate import --include="src/data/indonesia-cities.json"
```

This will rewrite your Git history to move the large file into LFS.

Step 3: Add and Commit Changes
Now you should stage and commit the .gitattributes file and the large file itself:

```bash
git add .gitattributes src/data/indonesia-cities.json
git commit -m "Migrate large file to Git LFS"
```

Step 4: Push to Remote Repository
Finally, push your changes to your remote repository:

```bash
git push origin your-branch-name
```

Note: Be cautious when using history rewriting commands like git lfs migrate, especially on shared repositories. Always backup your repository and inform your collaborators to re-clone after such changes.

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/moving-a-file-in-your-repository-to-git-large-file-storage